# Locate XML node with specific attribute and change it

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have looked through several threads here on how to locate an XML node and change an attribute. However, I cannot find a solution to my problem:

I have an XML node which has several nodes under it with the same name (but different attributes). For example:

```
<Configuration>
  <ConfigOptions>
    <add key="Localize" value="Off" />
    <add key="Cache" value="Database" />
    <add key= etc........
```

I need to use a simple VBScript to locate the `<add>` node where `key="Cache"` and then change the value to something else.

Comment: First, understand exactly what you are trying to find.  I suggest reviewing A beginner's guide to the XML DOM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx. The key in   key="Cache" is an attribute.  Also, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225958/using-asp-vb-to-get-value-of-a-node-attribute.  Then, add the code you've tried and where you're getting stuck.

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782233/603855 helps.

Answer (score 4):

use [xpath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) to select the node

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.load strXMLPath
Set node = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//Configuration/ConfigOptions/add[@key='Cache']")
strOldValue = node.item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("value").text
```

then change the value

```
node.item(0).attributes.getNamedItem("value").text = strNewValue
```

then save the xml file

```
xmlDoc.save strXMLPath
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and did the job. Thanks a lot!